# Control an empty desktop computer from my laptop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Can I somehow control a completely empty desktop computer from my laptop?

The new desktop computer should eventually become a server. I would like to set up the desktop from my laptop. Is it possible? and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Define: "empty desktop"
Also include some more details like Operating System.

Comment: A new computer. It has no operating system yet.

Comment: How would you propose to control it if it has no operating system?

Comment: With some cables of some sort. It is so that I don't need to buy keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could purchase an IPKVM, connect the desktop computer to it, and access it from the laptop via your network. You could also purchase a standard 2 host KVM and connect both computers to it if both of them are withing reach of the KVM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this perhaps ([usb kvm](http://www.startech.com/item/NOTECONS01-Portable-USB-PS-2-KVM-Console-Adapter-for-Notebook-PCs.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

If it will become a server you don't need monitor, mouse and keyboard. Take those from another computer to install some OS, afterwards you can administer it via SSH or similar.